# angularJS - updating/re-evaluating ng-disabled condition?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    <button ng-disabled="{{item.cost > vm.currency}}"> cost:50 </button>
</div>
```

controller.js:

```
function Controller() {
    let vm = this;
    vm.currency = 0;
    vm.foo = foo;

    function foo() {
        vm.currency += 100;
    }
    ....
```

How to make it so, if foo() is called, and the ng-disabled condition would evaluate to false, it would update and stop disabling the button?

Calling $scope.$apply() throws a $apply already in progress error.

Comment: `ng-disabled="item.cost > vm.currency"`

Comment: As @PierreEmmanuelLallemant pointed out indirectly, you don't need to use interpolation with most (all?) Angular directives.

Comment: there are some, like `ng-src`, which require it.